# How to pull up flutter Text?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm trying to code a web site with Flutter.

I have a screen like this:

[image]

The text in the middle is just a little bit below. I want to take it a little higher. How can I do that?

Codes:

```
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("indexBackground.gif"),
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4), BlendMode.dstATop),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 55,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text("3D Modelleme Hizmeti", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    ],
  ),
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the [EdgeInsets.fromLTRB constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets/EdgeInsets.fromLTRB.html). In this example I increased the bottom padding to 30.0 which will raise up the text, you should adjust it to what works best for you.

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 30.0),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("indexBackground.gif"),
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4), BlendMode.dstATop),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 55,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  "3D Modelleme Hizmeti",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```